# Bringing korbanos for prior obligations when bais hamikdash is rebuilt

Tags: beis-hamikdash, korban

I remember learning that there were very prominent Rabbaniom (Chafetz Chaim) who would write down which korbanos he would be obligated to bring when the Bais hamikdash would be built . Why do we assume that one is obligated to bring a korban when there is no bais hamikdash. whats the source that one would need to bring all the korbanos they would be obligated in when the Bais hamikdash is built ?

Also do we find that the last generation of the people from  before the building of the second temple brought a bunch of korbanos for all prior obligations once the temple was built ?

Comment: There's no fundamental difference in chiyuv today, it's just a case of oneis.  It's like if you have to do pidyon haben but there's no kohen around - you have to do it once you find a kohen.

Comment: Already in the Gemara the Amoraim would keep lists

Comment: @DoubleAA Tannaim https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.12b.5?lang=bi

Answer (score 0):

The Gemara (Shabbos 12b and Yuma 80a) list *tanaim* who kept records of their transgressions with the intention of bringing *karbanot* when the *Beis Hamikdash* will be rebuilt. The Magen Avraham (O"CH 334.33) codifies the obligation to keep record of any obligation that requires a *korban*.

The *R"ma Mipano*, famously quoted in the Bnei Yissaschar (Rosh Chodesh, Maamar 2), supposedly held that we will sacrifice all the daily offerings that we have missed since the destruction of the temple. This could be a possible explanation to what we say in Tefillas Mussaf - ואת מוסף יום השבת הזה נעשה ונקריב לפניך - *the Mussaf of this Shabbos we will perform and sacrifice before You*, indicating that we will in fact make up the missing *Karbanos*. This is contradictory to the dictum "עבר זמנו בטל קרבנו", which would indicate that we cannot make up for missing Korbanot after their time has passed.

Others (particularly in the Chassidish world) suggest that since we have a replacement for *Karbanot* (Menachos 110) by virtue of learning the Halachos of the Korbon, we will not be obligated to bring Karbanot when the Beis Hamikdash is rebuilt. This seems, however, contradictory to the Gemara (Shabbas 12b, Yuma 80a).

The prevalent custom, it seems, is not to keep records of transgressions.

Comment: I don't understand how that gemara proves that it is obligatory, one can simply say that they were scrupulous with this Inyun.  Also what did they do when the second bais hamikdash was rebuilt ,did they have 1000s of korbanos

Comment: Sam - One cannot bring a Korban Chatas voluntarily; it can only be brought if it is obligatory. If R' Yishmoel planned on bringing in, he would have to have thought it obligatory. And in Yuma 80, the Gemara isn't relating a story, it is instructing.

Comment: Thats not what I meant,I meant that if one is obligated to bring a chatas if there was a bais hamikdash then they were scrupulous with this Inyun, but not necessarily is one obligated if there is no mikdash. Also this was not codified by the great halachists, why?(The fact that MA is the only one proves that this isn't common practice) either it is obligatory or not

Comment: Sam - R' Yishmoel sinned when there was no Beis Hamikdash, yet planned on bringing one upon its rebuilding. This proves that he was obligated, otherwise he would be forbidden from bringing a "voluntary" Chatas.

Comment: As to why the Poskim don't mention it, I think I remember seeing a source explain that we will have to bring Karbanos as per Gemara Shabbos etc., but we will don't have to keep a record, because Eliyahu (or Urim veTumim) will tell us all what we are required to bring. I can't place the source offhand...